# Let $f : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ be a linear map. Prove that there is a constant $a ∈ \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = a x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have established $\operatorname{Img}f=\Bbb R$. Is this correct, or even relevant to the question, and how do I proceed from here?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is linear, and does not have that image.

Comment: Oh. So how do I prove this?

Comment: Have you a concept of *basis*? What is the relevance of $f(1)$ to $f(x)$?

Comment: Let $a=f(x)/x$ for some $x\ne0$.  For all $x'\in\mathbb R$, let $c=x'/x$.  Then $f(x')=f(cx)=cf(x)=cax=acx=ax'$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please consider to update your question with better formatting such as using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As to your question: A good start would be to just write down the definition of a linear map.

Comment: @Arthur Ok, let $f$ be a **non trivial** linear map.

Comment: @K.defaoite it doesn't have to be. $0$ is a perfectly reasonable real number and it does define a linear transformation. We don't have to exclude that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f$ is a linear map, we have:

$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R, \forall \alpha \in \Bbb R,  f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)
$$

Let us take $x = 1$, above immediately gives: $\forall \alpha \in \Bbb R, f(\alpha) = \alpha f(1)$

Just rename $\alpha$ to $x$, and define $a = f(1)$. Above writes as:

$$ \forall x \in \Bbb R, f(x) = a x $$ CQFD.

Not only we have proven the existence of $a$, but also identified it as $f(1)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=f(x)/x$ for some $x\ne0$.

For all $x'\in\mathbb R$, let $c=x'/x$.

Then $f(x')=f(cx)=cf(x)=cax=acx=ax'$.

(Note that $f(cx)=cf(x)$ because $f$ is linear.)